# How can I get the notification bar in my full screen android app?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-notifications, android-fullscreen

I have got an android app that uses a surface view to display a preview of the camera. This is all in full screen. Now, the problem is that when I try to pull down the notification bar from the top, I don't get anything. I can't pull down any notification bar.

What is the problem here? I have seen other apps where this is possible so there must be some kind of setting for that. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

This can be what you want.
Don't use `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: But isn't `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` making my notification bar disappear? I WANT the notification menu in my fullscreen app!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your manifest it will show notification bar in full screen mode

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```